# Convert RSS date format to german date in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a little App which shows data from an RSS feed. Because it's date format is very long and now well for being printed out I want to convert it to the German's date format. This code I have now, but it always return "nil":

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
NSString *contentDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

What's wrong with it? Thanks for answers!

Comment: at what point is it nil? is date already nil or only the string at the end?

Comment: The String at the end. I tried to append it with `content = [content stringByAppendingString:contentDate];` and there was an error `[__NSCFString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument`

Comment: could you please output your input string and the value of date from line 3 as well?I think that parsing into date is the origin of the problem. There is probably nothing wrong with your output formatter...

Comment: When I try "stringByAppendingString:date" it crashes too (same error (nil)) but when I try "stringByAppendingString:dateString" it works (but format is wrong) So maybe the error is in creating the NSdate from string.

Comment: +1 on mike suggestion, although it would be nice to see an example of the real feed.

Answer (score 1):

RSS dates are a bit tricky.. you can grab the NSDate+InternetDateTime.h/.m from here:
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

that should take care of the hard work.